# Angular Resize <img />

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm working on an web site ( html , css , js [AngularJS] )

I have to display pictures, which have different original width and height, one at a time, in the same element. So i wanted to create a  tag with dynamic source and dimensions

I would like to do this :

```
[HTML] : <img id="previewImage" ng-show="main.selectedFileSource != ''" 
            style="width:{{main.selectedFileWidth}};
            height:{{main.selectedFileHeight}};
            position: absolute; top: 0; bottom:0; left: 0; right:0; margin: auto" 
            src="{{main.selectedFileSource}}" />
```

The source changes work fine but the problem comes with width and height

I have inputs to change selectedFileWidth/Height, but when I change them, my  dimensions don't change...

I tried to use a function which could apply changes ( $scope.$apply() ) but it didn't solve it.

I tried to use ng-style="{...}" instead of style

I also tried  this :

```
var img = document.getElementById('previewImage')
img.style.height = XXX
img.style.width = YYY
```

Still not working ... It looks like dimensions are locked since  is already created. Should I delete the previous tag and create a new one each time I change the picture i want to display ?

Any idea ? Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.element("#previewImage").height("100px").width("100px);
```

Give that a go. `angular.element` automatically updates the view and so on.

`angular.element(selector)` is basically the same as jQuery's `$(selector)`.

Comment: 10 points for Gryffindor ! Can't accept answer yet , but it worked thanks

Comment: @SonnyJayet Haha, I understood that reference. You're welcome!